# How would I parse this XML with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, xml

Currently, I have an XML document (called Food_Display_Table.xml) with data in a format like this:

```
<Food_Display_Table>
    <Food_Display_Row>
        <Food_Code>12350000</Food_Code>
        <Display_Name>Sour cream dip</Display_Name>
        ....
        <Solid_Fats>105.64850</Solid_Fats>
        <Added_Sugars>1.57001</Added_Sugars>
        <Alcohol>.00000</Alcohol>
        <Calories>133.65000</Calories>
        <Saturated_Fats>7.36898</Saturated_Fats>
    </Food_Display_Row>
    ...
</Food_Display_Table>
```

I would like to print some of this information in human readable format. Like this:

```
-----
Sour cream dip
Calories: 133.65000
Saturated Fats: 7.36898
-----
```

So far, I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
require 'rexml/document'
include REXML

data = Document.new File.new("Food_Display_Table.xml", "r")

data.elements.each("*/*/*") do |foodcode, displayname, portiondefault, portionamount, portiondisplayname, factor, increments, multiplier, grains, wholegrains, orangevegetables, darkgreenvegetables, starchyvegetables, othervegetables, fruits, milk, meats, soy, drybeans, oils, solidfats, addedsugars, alcohol, calories, saturatedfats|
  puts "----"
  puts displayname
  puts "Calories: {calories}"
  puts "Saturated Fats: {saturatedfats}"
  puts "----"
end
```

Comment: Note that you never close your file handle, which is not a good idea (but unrelated to your troubles).

Comment: Nokogiri and Hpricot are good at parsing XML/HTML. Check out their doc, and they are both pretty easy to use.

Comment: I wonder why you would accept the answer that you did. It doesn't use REXML, it doesn't match your output directly, and the Nokogiri code is more complex than my Nokogiri code.

Comment: Hi, Phrogz, when I tried your Nokogiri code, the output wasn't correct. I don't think it takes into account that there are many <Food_Display_Row> records in the XML. I then tried the answer submitted by d11wtq, which worked fine, even though I did have to tweak the output a little, but that was no big deal.

Comment: @rps Great, thanks for the explanation. It does account for that just fine for me, but perhaps the XML file that I created with multiple rows (since you didn't supply an XML sample showing exactly what you have) somehow differs. The important thing is that you got your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Xpath.  I tend to go with Nokogiri as I prefer the API.

With the paths hard-coded:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_string)
doc.xpath(".//Food_Display_Row").each do |node|
  puts "-"*5
  puts "Name: #{node.xpath('.//Display_Name').text}"
  puts "Calories: #{node.xpath('.//Calories').text}"
  puts "Saturated Fats: #{node.xpath('.//Saturated_Fats').text}"
  puts "-"*5
end
```

or for something a bit DRYer.

```
nodes_to_display = ["Display_Name", "Calories", "Saturated_Fats"]

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_string)
doc.xpath(".//Food_Display_Row").each do |node|
  nodes_to_display.each do |node_name|
    if value = node.at_xpath(".//#{node_name}")
      puts "#{node_name}: #{value.text}"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this, with [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/):

```
require 'nokogiri' # gem install nokogiri
doc = Nokogiri::XML(IO.read('Food_Display_Table.xml'))

good_fields = %w[ Calories Saturated_Fats ]

puts "-"*5
doc.search("Food_Display_Row").each do |node|
  puts node.at('Display_Name').text
  node.search(*good_fields).each do |node|
    puts "#{node.name.gsub('_',' ')}: #{node.text}" 
  end
  puts "-"*5
end
```

If I had to use REXML (which I used to love, but now love Nokogiri more), the following works:

```
require 'rexml/document'
doc = REXML::Document.new( IO.read('Food_Display_Table.xml') )

separator = "-"*15
puts separator
desired = %w[ Calories Saturated_Fats ]
doc.root.elements.each do |row|
  puts REXML::XPath.first( row, 'Display_Name' ).text
  desired.each do |node_name|
    REXML::XPath.each( row, node_name ) do |node|
      puts "#{node_name.gsub('_',' ')}: #{node.text}"
    end
  end
  puts separator
end

#=> ---------------
#=> Sour cream dip
#=> Calories: 133.65000
#=> Saturated Fats: 7.36898
#=> ---------------
```